# Session IDs Growing Very Large Randomly

Tags: asp.net, iis, session, iis-7, sessionid

We have a table and logging mechanism that logs customers that log in with a Session ID. However, one thing we notice is that sometimes the Session ID information tends to grow quite large growing beyond a 255 character ID. How can we stop it from doing this?

Comment: Is this happening with the standard ASP.NET in-proc session manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page seems to discuss the subject http://forums.asp.net/p/1264093/2370866.aspx

It seems you need to make your own session manager